# How to find max salary with empoyee Id in every particular department in JAVA?

Tags: java

```
/* Save this in a file called Main.java to compile and test it */

/* Do not add a package declaration */
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

/* DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING ABOVE THIS LINE */
/* You may add any imports here, if you wish, but only from the 
   standard library */

/* Do not add a namespace declaration */
public class Main {
    public static Map<String, Integer> processData(ArrayList<String> array) {
        /*
         * Modify this method to process `array` as indicated in the question.
         * At the end, return the appropriate value.
         *
         * Please create appropriate classes, and use appropriate data
         * structures as necessary.
         *
         * Do not print anything in this method.
         *
         * Submit this entire program (not just this method) as your answer
         */
        Map<String, Integer> retVal = new Map<String, Integer>();
        for (Employee employee : array) {
            int highSalary = retVal.get(employee.getDepartment());
            if (highSalary == null || highSalary < employee.getSalary()) {
                retVal.put(employee.getDepartment(), employee.getSalary());
            }
        }
        return retVal;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> inputData = new ArrayList<String>();
        String line;
        try {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt")));
            while (in.hasNextLine())
                inputData.add(in.nextLine());
            Map<String, Integer> retVal = processData(inputData);
            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt")));
            for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : retVal.entrySet())
                output.println(e.getKey() + ": " + e.getValue());
            output.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IO error in input.txt or output.txt");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the input.txt file:

```
22, Rajan Anand, Engineering, 1600000
23, Swati Patil, Testing, 800000
27, Vijay Chawda, Engineering, 800000
29, Basant Mahapatra, Engineering, 600000
32, Ajay Patel, Testing, 350000
34, Swaraj Birla, Testing, 350000
```

I've created one Employee class and tried with getter setter but it's not working at. How can I approach this question please help me out

Expected result:

```
Engineering: 22
Testing: 23
```

Class definition:

```
public class Employee {
    private int salary;
    private String department;
    private int employeeId;
    private String name;

    public Employee(int salary, String department, int employeeId, String name) {
        this.salary = salary;
        this.department = department;
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(int salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public String getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(String department) {
        this.department = department;
    }

    public int getEmployeeId() {
        return employeeId;
    }

    public void setEmployeeId(int employeeId) {
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

I created Employee class exclusively by encapsulation but I am gettinng compilation errors. Please help me out with I stuck on this from last 2 days.
But I want to do it without Employee class

Comment: It's pretty obvious but I think you should mention it is a school assignment or similar. Also post code for Employee and how you tried to use it.

Comment: What did you try to do your school assignment?

Comment: well it's not my school assignment it's just I got a question in my paper so I can't able to solved it that's why I asked here.

Comment: Why all the `\``?

Comment: @dquijada I was trying to showing in boxes. Please help me out with this.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I updated my code please help me out with this.

Comment: What is the exact compilation error you are getting ?

Comment: I can help you but let's go to the chat, I don't want to spam the rest

Comment: @funkyjelly I am getting the error `The public class must be named as Main in your Java code.`

Comment: okay @TsakiroglouFotis lets go to chat

Comment: You have 2 subtask: a->Read the file b->create a collection and sort it

Comment: @TsakiroglouFotis can you please elaborate it more.

Comment: @Divyank Vijayvergiya I'll do in 2 hours bcs right now I am in a middle of a regression.I hope 2 hours is ok for you.I'll have to return home first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187434/discussion-between-divyank-vijayvergiya-and-tsakiroglou-fotis).

Answer (score 2):

1. First, you need to parse each line of the file into an Employee.
2. Next, you need to figure out how to keep track of the highest-earning employee. You will need to later retrieve their ID. So you must store the entire object.

Instead of a `Map<String, Integer>`, you will want to use a `Map<String, Employee>`. As you iterate over each Employee, you can compare the current employee with the one retrieved from the map (by Department). If the current Employee has a higher salary, you will replace the one in the map (for that Department) with the current one.

### Example

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    /**
     * Convert a list of Employees into a Map of Departments with the
     * highest-earning Employee
     */
    public static Map<String, Employee> processData(List<Employee> employees) {
        // Need to store the ENTIRE Employee as the value to compare salary and
        // later retrieve the ID
        Map<String, Employee> result = new HashMap<String, Employee>();
        for (Employee employee : employees) {
            Employee currEmployee = result.get(employee.getDepartment());
            if (currEmployee == null || currEmployee.getSalary() < employee.getSalary()) {
                result.put(employee.getDepartment(), employee);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    /** Parse a line into an Employee */
    public static Employee parseLine(String line) {
        String[] tokens = line.split(", ");
        int id = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0], 10);     // Position 1
        int salary = Integer.parseInt(tokens[3], 10); // Position 4
        String name = tokens[1];                      // Position 2
        String department = tokens[2];                // Position 3
        return new Employee(salary, department, id, name);
    }

    /** Load a file containing Employee info */
    public static List<Employee> loadFile(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
        ArrayList<Employee> result = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename)));
        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            // Parse each line into an Employee object.
            result.add(parseLine(in.nextLine()));
        }
        in.close();
        return result;
    }

    /** Write each Department's highest-earning Employee's ID */
    public static void writeData(Map<String, Employee> data, String filename) throws IOException {
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename)));
        output.print(data.entrySet().stream()
                .map(e -> e.getKey() + ": " + e.getValue().getEmployeeId())
                .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator())));
        output.close();
    }

    /** Main entry */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            writeData(processData(loadFile("input.txt")), "output.txt");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IO error in input.txt or output.txt");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

3 issues spotted in your Main class :

1) You didn't import your Employee class

```
import <your_package_name>.Employee;
```

2) You can't instantiate a Map. I assume you need a HashMap :

```
Map<String, Integer> retVal = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

3) your "array" variable is an arraylist of strings `ArrayList<String>`, it cannot be transformed to Employee object so this loop is incorrect :

```
for (Employee employee : array)
```

Comment: good catch.Well done mate.Maybe I would use SortedMap<Employee> and sort with a comparator to salary

Comment: I can't add a package declaration I want to do it without Employee Class and anyways they both are in same package

Comment: @Divyank then remove all your employee references in your code, correct your for loop in your Main class to process the strings `for (String s : array)` and do all the needed logic inside that loop

Comment: @funkyjelly but I am not getting logic too can you please elaborate more

Comment: See @Mr.Polywhirl answer. It's the proper way to do it and by using Employee domain object.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the employee department and his salary by the highest employee id using following way :

```
public static Map<String, Integer> processData(ArrayList<String> array) {
    Map<String, Integer> retVal = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    Map<String, Map<Integer, Integer>> resultMap = new HashMap<String, Map<Integer, Integer>>();

    for (String empDetails : array) {
        String[] data = empDetails.split(",");
        if (resultMap.containsKey(data[2])) {
            Map<Integer, Integer> empIdSalaryMap = resultMap.get(data[2]);
            if (empIdSalaryMap.keySet().iterator().next() < Integer.parseInt(data[0])) {
                retVal.put(data[2], Integer.parseInt(data[3].trim()));
            }
        } else {
            Map<Integer, Integer> empIdSalaryMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
            empIdSalaryMap.put(Integer.parseInt(data[0]), Integer.parseInt(data[3].trim()));
            resultMap.put(data[2], empIdSalaryMap);
            retVal.put(data[2], Integer.parseInt(data[3].trim()));
        }
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        List<String> inputData = new ArrayList<String>();
        String line;
        try {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("G:\\input.txt")));
            while (in.hasNextLine()) {
                inputData.add(in.nextLine());
            }
            Map<String, Integer> retVal = processData(inputData);
            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("G:\\\\output.txt")));
            for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : retVal.entrySet()) {
                output.println(e.getKey() + ": " + e.getValue());
            }
            output.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IO error in input.txt or output.txt");
        }
    }

    public static Map<String, Integer> processData(ArrayList<String> array) {
    
        Map<String, Integer> retVal = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        Map<String, Integer> resultMap1 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        for (String empDetails : array) {
            
            String[] data = empDetails.split(",");

            if (resultMap1.containsKey(data[2])) {

                if (resultMap1.get(data[2]) < Integer.parseInt(data[3].trim())) {
                    resultMap1.put(data[2].toString(), Integer.parseInt(data[3].trim()));
                    retVal.put(data[2].toString().trim(), Integer.parseInt(data[0].trim()));
                }

            } else {
                resultMap1.put(data[2].toString(), Integer.parseInt(data[3].trim()));
                retVal.put(data[2].toString().trim(), Integer.parseInt(data[0].trim()));
            }

        }
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Map<Integer,String> collect = empList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getDeptId(),
                    Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparingDouble(Employee::getSalary)),value->value.get().getName())));
```

> Using Collectors from java 8 onwards

Answer (score -1):

```
/* Do not add a package declaration */

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

/* DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING ABOVE THIS LINE */
/* You may add any imports here, if you wish, but only from the 
   standard library */

/* Do not add a namespace declaration */
public class Main {
    public static Map<String, Integer> processData(ArrayList<String> array) {
        

        Map<String, Integer> finalMap = new HashMap<>();

        Map<String, Map<Integer, Integer>> map = new HashMap<String, Map<Integer, Integer>>();
        for (String s : array) {
            String breakdata[] = s.split(",");
            if (map.get(breakdata[2]) != null) {
                map.get(breakdata[2]).put(Integer.parseInt(breakdata[0]), Integer.parseInt(breakdata[3].trim()));
            } else {
                Map<Integer, Integer> inner = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
                inner.put(Integer.parseInt(breakdata[0]), Integer.parseInt(breakdata[3].trim()));
                map.put(breakdata[2], inner);
            }
        }
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Map<Integer, Integer>>> itr = map.entrySet().iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String, Map<Integer, Integer>> parent = itr.next();
            finalMap.put(parent.getKey(), parent.getValue().entrySet().stream().max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).get().getKey());

        }


        return finalMap;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> inputData = new ArrayList<String>();
        String line;
        try {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt")));
            while (in.hasNextLine())
                inputData.add(in.nextLine());
            Map<String, Integer> retVal = processData(inputData);
            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt")));
            for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : retVal.entrySet())
                output.println(e.getKey() + ": " + e.getValue());
            output.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IO error in input.txt or output.txt");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Kindly add explanations to your solution. Especially what you changed and why.

Comment: Create a Map<String, Map<Integer, Integer>>.  The outer map contain Department as key and inner map contain Employee_ID as key and Employee_Salary as Value , then find the max salary and return the Employee_ID and insert into the required map Department as key and employee_Id as values.

Comment: In your Answer please. Not in comments.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
    public static Map<String,Integer> processData(ArrayList<String> array) {
                
        Map<String, Integer> retVal = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        Map<String, Map<Integer, Integer>> resultMap = new HashMap<String, Map<Integer, Integer>>();

        for (String empDetails : array) {
            String[] data = empDetails.split(",");
            if (resultMap.containsKey(data[2])) {
                Map<Integer, Integer> empIdSalaryMap = resultMap.get(data[2]);
                if (empIdSalaryMap.keySet().iterator().next() < Integer.parseInt(data[0])) {
                    retVal.put(data[2], Integer.parseInt(data[3].trim()));
                }
            } else {
                Map<Integer, Integer> empIdSalaryMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
                empIdSalaryMap.put(Integer.parseInt(data[0]), Integer.parseInt(data[3].trim()));
                resultMap.put(data[2], empIdSalaryMap);
                retVal.put(data[2], Integer.parseInt(data[3].trim()));
            }
        }       
       return retVal;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> inputData = new ArrayList<String>();
        String line;
        try {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt")));
            while(in.hasNextLine())
                inputData.add(in.nextLine());
            Map<String,Integer> retVal = processData(inputData);
            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt")));
            for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> e: retVal.entrySet())
                output.println(e.getKey() + ": " + e.getValue());
            output.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IO error in input.txt or output.txt");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's always better to give à piece of explanation on how the code you propose answer the question.